# Missing or invalid 'android' section in rhobuild.yml:

Tags: rhomobile

I am using RhoStudio to build a test application and it is giving me this error

```
Missing or invalid 'android' section in rhobuild.yml:
```

I tried googling it but I couldn't figure out the problem.

Comment: Have you configured the RhoMobile environment as described in the guide and which version of RhoMobile, Java JDK, Android SDK and NDK are you using? Could you post your `build.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have to configure Android in build.yml file. That file is in the root folder of the proyect and is different of RhoBuild.yml since the last one configure variables for the Rho building environment and build.yml only configures the build of your app.
Try creating a blank app and locating that file in the root folder.